# Try to make horizontal bootstrap form with three column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make horizontal form with three field but I am facing space issue between label and input type.

[image: 1]

I want to reduce space between label and input.

HTML code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="row">
           
    
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputKey" class="col-md-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Key">
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputValue" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputValue" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputKey" class="col-md-2 control-label">State</label>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSt" placeholder="ST">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="Zip">
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputValue" class="col-md-2 control-label">Other</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </form>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: The spacing is coming from the `col` classes you are using. Either use smaller columns or put the label and input into the same column.

Comment: when I put the label and input into same column then label comes above the input.

Comment: Then try using a smaller column for the label?

Comment: col-sm-2 is also not working for smaller column

Comment: I meant to use `col-md-1` rather than `col-md-2`. That gives 1/12 of the space to the label instead of 1/6. The `sm` in `col-sm-2` is for the screensize rather than the column size.

Comment: In col-md-1,label is not fit properly.

Comment: The `col` classes are what gives it the grid layout and makes the inputs responsive, so if that doesn't work, you are going to need custom CSS or a different layout. What exactly do you want it to look like when you remove the space - should the text box move to beside the label, or do you still want the form to be in columns with all the labels being the same size?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the col-sm-2 in your label. You can also check the my code below, it could save more space.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="row">
           
    
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="inputKey" class=" control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Key">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputValue" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputValue" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="inputKey" class=" control-label">State</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSt" placeholder="ST">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="inputKey" class="control-label">zip</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="Zip">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputValue" class=" control-label">Other</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </form>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h3>Or remove the col-sm for labels.</h3>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form >
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
        </form>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

**Open the snippet in full page.**

Comment: hi thanks but last input type is not responsive as size of screen reduces. You can also see in snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just put label and input in same column that is in my case `col-md-4` and give it a class like `columns`. and

```css
.columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

label {
    width: 6rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
      <form class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group row">
                  
                  <div class="col-md-4 columns">
                    <label for="inputKey" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Key">
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="col-md-4 columns">
                    <label for="inputValue" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="col-md-4 columns">
                    <label for="inputValue" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```